# Detect non b/g/n 2.4 Ghz frequencies with wireless card?

Tags: wireless-networking

Can I detect and pair 2.4 Ghz frequencies with a wireless card, from other devices that are not router/modem ?

What I want to test is to connect and pair my wireless card with a wireless device, working with 2.4 Ghz, can this be done?

The reason of this is that I want to try to connect to a Wireless controller working on 2.4 Ghz band and receive it's data, can i do this with a wireless card?

Comment: What sort of devices are you trying to connect with?  If you want to connect your computer directly to another network-capable wireless device without using a router between them, you could set up an ad-hoc network.  But if you want to listen in on non-802.11 radio bands you'll likely need a spectrum analyzer, as the hardware in normal wireless cards aren't designed to listen to anything but digital wi-fi channels.

Comment: Yes, non b/g/n bands. something that is between 2.399 - 2.500 Ghz @Zel

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done (well, perhaps it can, but it would take serious firmware and possibly hardware hacking which, if you were capable of it, you wouldn't be asking the question in the first place).

A wireless card is designed and programmed to *exact* specifications which, by definition, excludes other non-compatible specifications.